# Does Keycloak support pagination and sorting of users list?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm working on a project using Angular - Spring boot - Keycloak 16.0 and one of the requirements is for the user to be able to fetch the user's list from Keycloak paginated, filtered and sorted by a user attribute (ex. email, username, etc.).

Based on [Keycloak's documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/16.0/rest-api/#_users_resource) and by reading the [source code on Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java) filtering and pagination is possible, but there's no sorting feature (the result seems always sorted by username):

```
/**
 * Get users
 *
 * Returns a stream of users, filtered according to query parameters.
 *
 * @param search A String contained in username, first or last name, or email
 * @param last A String contained in lastName, or the complete lastName, if param "exact" is true
 * @param first A String contained in firstName, or the complete firstName, if param "exact" is true
 * @param email A String contained in email, or the complete email, if param "exact" is true
 * @param username A String contained in username, or the complete username, if param "exact" is true
 * @param emailVerified whether the email has been verified
 * @param idpAlias The alias of an Identity Provider linked to the user
 * @param idpUserId The userId at an Identity Provider linked to the user
 * @param firstResult Pagination offset
 * @param maxResults Maximum results size (defaults to 100)
 * @param enabled Boolean representing if user is enabled or not
 * @param briefRepresentation Boolean which defines whether brief representations are returned (default: false)
 * @param exact Boolean which defines whether the params "last", "first", "email" and "username" must match exactly
 * @param searchQuery A query to search for custom attributes, in the format 'key1:value2 key2:value2'
 * @return a non-null {@code Stream} of users
 */
@GET
@NoCache
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Stream<UserRepresentation> getUsers(@QueryParam("search") String search,
                                           @QueryParam("lastName") String last,
                                           @QueryParam("firstName") String first,
                                           @QueryParam("email") String email,
                                           @QueryParam("username") String username,
                                           @QueryParam("emailVerified") Boolean emailVerified,
                                           @QueryParam("idpAlias") String idpAlias,
                                           @QueryParam("idpUserId") String idpUserId,
                                           @QueryParam("first") Integer firstResult,
                                           @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResults,
                                           @QueryParam("enabled") Boolean enabled,
                                           @QueryParam("briefRepresentation") Boolean briefRepresentation,
                                           @QueryParam("exact") Boolean exact,
                                           @QueryParam("q") String searchQuery)
```

My question is, is there something that I'm missing? Has anyone run into the same problem who can suggest me a possible solution?

Comment: Currently, there is no support to sort users by email, users are by default sorted by username. I would suggest you to pitch this enhancement in keycloak community or create Rest API in front of Keycloak API that will sort the users for you according to email